# Connecting router through (potentially) multiple celluar hot spots

Tags: wireless-router, home-networking, cellular-internet

I am having an issue (both technical and customer-service-oriented) with my ADSL ISP, and I'm now considering just dropping them and moving up to unlimited cellular plans for my wife and me.  The cost different is no contest.  (The difference to bump up two cell plans to unlimited is significantly less than what I'm paying for home internet.)

I've run speed tests on both:

- ADSL: 3-8 Mbps down / <1 Mbps up  (depending on time of day)
- Cellular: 50+ Mbps down / 2-3 Mbps up

Really, to me, this seems like no question.  I just need to figure out the details of *how*.

In a perfect world, I'd upgrade to fiber (or even VDSL), but neither are available in my area.

### Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Keep my router as the main wireless connection point for the myriad of other devices we have.
2. Conditionally, use one of two phones (mine or my wife's) as the connection to the internet.  If I'm home, use mine; otherwise use hers.

### Here's what I have so far:

I think I need a wireless bridge to tether the router to the hot spot, but I'm not sure.  I've seen several sites explaining how to do this for master/slave configuration of two routers, but nothing using a phone as the internet source.

I can set up both phones to broadcast the same NID (with the same password), but I'm not sure they'd both be able to broadcast at the same time or what would happen if they tried.  If that's the case, then we may need to manage whose is broadcasting manually.  I'd prefer an automatic solution.  Secondarily, would the router be able to reconnect automatically if the network were to become unavailable then available again (we leave home, then return)?

I'm not sure if the other devices would connect to the router or to the phone or if it matters.

I still need to talk with my cellular carrier to see what options there are for a internet-dedicated cell device on the same plan.  But I foresee that being something like just adding another cell plan, which would negate the cost-effectiveness of my plan.

---

For what it's worth, I'm a software dev, not a network guy.  Maybe that information will help in wording your explanations; maybe not.

Comment: Just a small caveat ― some carriers are well aware that their customers may use their services as "home" WiFi and may not take kindly to "excessive" usage. Most carriers (in the US at least) have relatively low [soft caps](https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/19/16334690/t-mobile-unlimited-data-cap-increase-32gb-50gb-deprioritization) where they will slow your data, if nothing else. And the amount of data even one person can use might be surprising.

Comment: I'm well aware of the amount of data we use as a household.  We stream youtube, netflix, and nhl constantly :)

Comment: Lol! Well, in that case, I wish you good luck. =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I rewrote this a few times but it always ends up being jumbled and confusing. Sorry.*

> I think I need a wireless bridge to tether the router to the hot spot, but I'm not sure. I've seen several sites explaining how to do this for master/slave configuration of two routers but nothing using a phone as the internet source.

For your plan, the easiest method would be to use a single router which supports multiple uplinks (and automatic switching between them). This is a relatively common feature.

- Some routers even support connecting to wireless uplinks directly; I've done this in the past with a Mikrotik device.
- For those which only support wired uplinks, an additional "wireless bridge" will indeed be required. (Many "wireless extenders" can be switched to this mode.)
- Be careful though – some routers only support using a USB 3G/4G modem as the alternate uplink which makes them unsuitable for your plan.

If your existing LAN router doesn't support this, replace it with one which does. (If the old router is integrated with the ADSL modem, usually there's an option to switch off routing and use "bridge-only" or "modem-only" or "passthrough" mode.)

Two-router master/slave configuration is technically possible here, but it would require a bit more work and the required features aren't very common in consumer firmware, while the single-router multi-uplink option is far more widespread.

Also, you don't have to think of the phone as "a phone with hotspot enabled" – for all intents and purposes, it's a tiny router with Wi-Fi. Anything that works with wireless uplinks in general will work with phone hotspots as well.

> I can set up both phones to broadcast the same NID (with the same password), but I'm not sure they'd both be able to broadcast at the same time or what would happen if they tried.

Identical ESSIDs within the same area are legal, but they imply that a client can freely roam between the APs without killing connections. This is possible if all such access points provide access to exactly the same network, e.g. a university campus would have 100's of APs all on a single subnet.

But the above is *not* the case with phone hotspots – each of them acts as its own router; and even if the issued IP addresses look the same (e.g. both run standard Android hotspots), their networks are still fully separate. So in general, this would mean the phones should have different SSIDs.

Although on the other hand, I'm not sure which "wireless bridge" devices can even be given a list of SSIDs to try – many models accept only one at a time. In that situation, using the same SSID for both phones would be *possible* although problematic.

Comment: That's for taking the time.  It gives me enough information to continue and at least test my idea.